# How to Update Gridview with downloading images in android

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I want to download and show some images inside gridView adapter. Here is my Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    ArrayList<String> list = null;


    public CustomAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list= list;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
     */
    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     * android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent) {

                 //Inflating View
                  .....................


        GridItem gridItem = new GridItem (imageview);
        DownloadContent downloadContent = new DownloadContent();
        downloadContent.setDownloadUrl(list.get(0));
        downloadContent.setContentType(DownloadContent.CONTENT_TYPE_IMAGE);
        downloadContent.setDownloadFilePath(filepath);
        downloadContent.setDownloadNotifier(imageDownloadNotifier);
        downloadContent.setTag(gridItem);
        new DownloadTask(new DownloadContent[] { downloadContent }).execute();

//      
        return view;
    }

  private DownloadNotifier imageDownloadNotifier = new DownloadNotifier() {

    @Override
    public void downloadCompleted(DownloadContent downloadContent) {
        if(downloadContent.isSuccess())
        {
            GridItem gridItem = (GridItem) downloadContent.getTag();
            ImageView imgView = mgridItem.getImage();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(downloadContent.getDownloadFilePath());
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }
};

}
```

This shows the following exception

```
-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-24
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: **Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3020)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:634)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1157)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:257)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:322)
10-26 11:27:33.629: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageView.java:336)
```

How can I fix this? How can i update the view with respect to downloading images?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: **Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

This is the issue because you are trying to fetch images from web directly inside the main thread. Instead you should implement **Asynchronous image loading logic**.

I would suggest you to check and implement logic like: [Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: I am used Async task for downloading images and after completing the download it shows using the respective imageview.I think the problem is when updating imageview inside Downloadnotifier.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani - I think OP is trying to use (update or access) Main UI views in another Thread. And only Main UI thread can update the Views.